# How to serialize a hierarchy with abstract classes using protobuf

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm having some problems trying to serialize a hierarchy of classes using protobuf. The properties not implemented by the classes who inherits from the abstract class don't get the correct values. For example, when I try to test the following hierarchy...:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(11, typeof(Child))]
[ProtoInclude(12, typeof(Nanny))]
public abstract class Person
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Child : Person
{
    public Child(){ }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Nanny : Person
{
    public Nanny()
    {
        Tutors = new List<ITutor<Person, Person>>();
    }

    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public List<ITutor<Person, Person>> Tutors { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(11, typeof(NannyTutorChild))]
public interface ITutor<out T, out U>
    where T : Person
    where U : Person
{
    [ProtoMember(1, AsReference = true, DynamicType = true)]
    T TutoredBy { get; }

    [ProtoMember(2, AsReference = true, DynamicType = true)]
    U Tutored { get; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public abstract class Tutor<T, U> : ITutor<T, U>
    where T : Person
    where U : Person
{
    [ProtoMember(1, AsReference = true, DynamicType = true)]
    public T TutoredBy { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2, AsReference = true, DynamicType = true)]
    public U Tutored { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public abstract class NannyTutor<U> : Tutor<Nanny, U>
    where U : Person
{
}

[ProtoContract]
public class NannyTutorChild : NannyTutor<Child>
{
}
```

all the deserialized istances of NannyTutorChild are set to null, even though they're correctly valorized before calling Serializer.DeepClone(). The only way I found out to make it work is to mark as abstract the properties in the class Tutor, and implement them in NannyTutorChild.

I know it could look silly as hierarchy, but in our real project we have a lot of different classes derived from our 'Tutor' classm and all the levels are needed to typecast or use the correct methods :)

Any idea? Am I doing something wrong?

Thank you everyone,
Mat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This scenario is not currently supported; there's a complexity in the combination of `DynamicType` and inheritance that I still need to address; I will bump it forwards on my queue of pending work, but: it is not there today.

Comment: Thank you! I'll implement using abstract properties then :) 
Keep up the good work!

Comment: @VollmonD to emphasise, the DynamicType combination with inheritance is the key issue, I think