# C# ProtoBuf inheritance with generics

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

Imagine the following code example:

```cs
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(ExampleState))]
public abstract class BaseState<T>
{
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public T Model { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public string Id => this.Model.Id;
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ExampleState: BaseState<ExampleModel>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public DateTimeOffset LastSeenAt { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ExampleModel
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

when using protobuf-net. The `BaseState<T>` defines some `ProtoInclude` for `ExampleState`, but then the warning `PBN0012: The type 'ExampleState' is declared as an include, but is not a direct sub-type` is shown.

Is this desired behaviour or a bug? How does a workaround look like without having to re-write all models (In our case, this could get pretty complicated).

Comment: I couldn't chase the thread far enough to conclusion, but this was asked in '12 and @Mark-Gravell answered that it was incomplete at that time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883577/how-to-serialize-a-hierarchy-with-abstract-classes-using-protobuf

Comment: @Chris Thank you for the link. We somehow worked around this issue by updating our models, but I don't really remember how :D As far as I know, it's still an issue until now.